# Replace items in list for items from FirebaseDatabase data

Tags: xamarin.forms

Found a project that loads items in a CollectionView from a ViewModel for InfiniteScrolling.
But i want to replace the items with data from a FirebaseDatabase.

How do i make this work ?

There are 25 items in the ViewModel in `AddStudentInfo()`

```
    private async void AddStudentInfo()
    {

        StudentModel obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test1";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test2";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test3";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test4";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test5";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test6";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test7";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test8";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test9";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test10";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test11";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test12";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test13";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test14";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test15";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test16";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test17";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test18";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test19";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test20";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test21";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test22";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test23";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test24";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);

        obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Plaats = "Test25";
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);
  
    }
```

I can load data with this from a FirebaseDatabase.

```
  var GetItems = (await fc
          .Child("Verhaal")
          .OnceAsync<StudentModel>()).Select(item => new StudentModel
          {
              Adres = item.Object.Adres,
              Plaats = item.Object.Plaats
          }).ToList(); // had to add this .ToList() to make the answer from Jessie to work.
```

What do i have to change to make this work. Items from `Adres to obj.Adres` etc.

```
 var GetItems = (await fc
        .Child("Verhaal")
        .OnceAsync<StudentModel>()).Select(item => new StudentModel

        {            
        Adres = item.Object.Adres,
        Plaats = item.Object.Plaats
        }).ToList(); // had to add this .ToList() to make the answer from Jessie to work.

         // Change it in to this 

        StudentModel obj = new StudentModel();
        obj.Adres = "test@gmail.com";
        obj.Plaats = "Test1";
        _allStudentList.Add(obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `async-await` to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code:

```
   public ObservableCollection<StudentModel> AllStudentList { get; set; }

    AllStudentList = new ObservableCollection<StudentModel>();


    private async  void LoadData()
    {

        AllStudentList = new ObservableCollection<StudentModel>();
        
        //GetItems should be a list
        var GetItems = (await fc
    .Child("Verhaal")
    .OnceAsync<StudentModel>()).Select(item => new StudentModel

    {
        Adres = item.Object.Adres,
        Plaats = item.Object.Plaats
    });

        foreach (var item in GetItems) {

            AllStudentList.Add(item);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jessie , i had to add .ToList(); after getting Adres and Plaats. I update the answer with remark. Thanks